# Why is nulling a value faster than undefining it (javascript v8)

Tags: javascript, v8

Heyho tested a bit around with maps vs objects in Javascript and found out that nulling is much faster (2,5 times) than putting the value to undefined or compared to simply delete the property

https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15592/0/compare-nulling-undefining-and-deleting-of-javascript-o

If you are wondering why i allways create the map and or the javascript Object i did it so that every test has the same "overhead".

EDIT:
also got this one which got a logical mistake in it(setting a value to from null to null or setting it from undefined to undefined)
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15587/0/delete-vs-null-vs-undefined-vs-void-0-vs-objectcreatenu

and here the result is a bit more extreme 4mio ops (from null to null) vs 4k ops (undefined to undefined)

I know the test isnt really relevant its pure interest im asking :).

Comment: Except for the `delete` statement, they're all getting around a million operations per second for me. Do you need more operations per second than that?

Comment: no i dont need Speed its just pure interest also i got a test (tbh with a logical mistake^^) that got much worth results
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15587/0/delete-vs-null-vs-undefined-vs-void-0-vs-objectcreatenu
like i said got a logical mistake in it but still intresting how much slower undefine and delete is (4million ops at null and only 4000 ops at undefined or delete) with a chromium based browser.
Firefox can set to undefined faster but delete is also slow.

Comment: Based solely on your title: it isn't. Assignment to null or assignment to undefined is equally fast. Also, remember that while for _answers_ an "edit" section makes sense (because answers live forever, and JS constantly changes, so today's answer may no longer be the right answer a year from now), for questions an edit section makes no sense at all: just update your post so that anyone reading it gets all the information they need. The fact that it wasn't as detailed 10 minutes ago is irrelevant for all future visitors =)

Comment: The Edit was Just a nice addition.
The Test i had from the start shows me that nulling is faster (even tho both actions are fast and get several millions ops) so i wondered if there is some kind of optimization or maybe something else behind it :).

Comment: Whatever the reason you shouldn't make any assumption based on these results. Engines optimization is a dark science and a minor grain of salt will produce completely different results. For instance, if in your last benchmark you remove your inner loop, then in SpiderMonkey (Firefox) undefined comes a lot closer to null than when that inner loop is there. Always measure your own code, in real conditions with real data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

**Microbenchmarks are misleading!** Don't waste your time on them.

Setting an object property to `null` or to `undefined` has the same speed. Guaranteed.

Considering the significant difference that your test reproducibly shows, I got curious and dug in a bit. Turns out measurethat.net's framework code is... let's say... far from perfect: it uses "direct `eval`" in a way that introduces huge performance artifacts for accessing globals (that's one of several reasons why "never use direct `eval`!" is common advice), and one of JavaScript's historical accidents is that while `null` is a reserved keyword, `undefined` is just a global variable. See here for how ridiculous it gets:
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15627/0/accessing-null-vs-undefined
If you know what's going on, you can sidestep the issue:
https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/15635/0/null-vs-undefined-iiffe
But keep in mind that in a real app that doesn't use `eval`, you wouldn't see any of these differences; you're just playing games with a bad benchmark runner there!

Another thing that's really weird on that site is that when editing test cases and "validating" them, they produce *very* different results (I've seen 100x!) compared to "running" them after submitting them.

In short, I wouldn't trust *any* of the reported numbers on that site.

All that said, it makes sense that `delete a.a` is slower, because deleting an object property is a more complicated operation than overwriting an existing property's value. Importantly (and your benchmark doesn't show this, because it's too simple!), deleting properties often has *non-local* effects, i.e. it's not the deletion itself that's necessarily slow, but other parts of your app might get slowed down as side effects. We generally recommend not to use the `delete` keyword at all. Deleting entries in Maps is a different story: that's perfectly fine, as Maps are built to support that efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript objects have to also account for which keys are "enumerable". Deleting a key removes it from the list of keys that enumerable. This is similar to removing an element from an array which is a slower operation than simply overriding a value with `null`.

I'm not sure why setting the value to `undefined` is slower. I would assume it's because of similar reasons as a missing key has a value of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it's because `delete` actually have to delete, compared to `null` that will just empty its content.

## Comparison

- Delete remove the property, making it slower but free some memory.
- Nullifying is faster but the property, while null, the property still exists.

An object with 3000 property that are null takes more space in the ram than an empty object.

## In conclusion

While performance and the technical aspects of JavaScript are very interesting, and performances in general should'nt be completely ignored, this is beyond unnoticeable and you should'nt care about it in real-life scenarios.

#### Note:

This is my personal understanding and should'nt be taken as official informations. Feel free to correct me in the comments.